# Finding EC2 instance ID for someone else's instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I use a public AMI from a third party which runs an nginx web server, and it uses the EC2 instance ID for the default admin password.  I'm trying to think of any vulnerabilities with this, if I do not change the default password.  Since the HTTPS server is public, is there any way someone could discover the EC2 instance ID?

I know this can be seen by anyone in my company who has `ec2:DescribeInstances` permission, but I'm not really concerned about that.  I just want to make sure no one outside can find it.

Answer (score 3):

*Off the top of my head and without considering any crazy specific scenarios, I do not believe it is possible for one to retrieve this information without exploiting some sort of 0-day vulnerability we presently don't know about.*

Now let's stop living in a perfect world and begin to threat model about what could potentially happen.

Depending on the functionality you have going on and some other variables, I don't think it is crazy to think the instance ID could be leaked in some manner. Let's say you exposed a web application and you had some functionality which took user input and did not validate this input, then I could see the instance ID potentially being capable of being leaked.

For all intensive purposes, let's say our host is hosting a web application which analyzes users' LinkedIn profiles and offers them career advice. In addition, let's assume that the web application poorly accepts input and does not validate that a spoofed URL has been provided instead of a LinkedIn URL, and it will provide the response details after it has made a request to the URL provided by the attacker.

Considering all these, if I was an attacker trying to get the instance ID of your host, I would navigate to the part of the web application which accepts my input and I would provide the following input, and considering the scenarios I posed above, an attacker could potentially get the desired information:

> `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

How I came up with that payload was I looked at:

> `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html#instance-metadata-ex-1`

I believe that if all these prerequisites were met, then this would potentially leak the instance ID.

But until all these scenarios exist, it is not likely. I have seen some web applications which allow you to add an integration to your website poorly validate input given by the user. As such, one can exploit a server side request vulnerability to attack the host.

I hope this is a good explanation of how it could potentially happen, but again, I don't think it is likely.

Comment: Excellent analysis! The metadata vulnerability is well-known, and is probably why AWS introduced Instance Metadata v2 (see [Add defense in depth against open firewalls, reverse proxies, and SSRF vulnerabilities with enhancements to the EC2 Instance Metadata Service | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/defense-in-depth-open-firewalls-reverse-proxies-ssrf-vulnerabilities-ec2-instance-metadata-service/)). So, activating v2 on the instance would certainly reduce potential leaks.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! It has been years since I used StackOverflow and I just realized I love answering these questions again =] Getting a +1 from someone like yourself is an honor =]

I also agree, this is fixed with v2 like you mentioned.